# What is the right way to link up an app in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm somewhat a beginner with Django and I'm wondering why people link up apps in settings.py in INSTALLED_APPS in 2 different ways. One is just the name of the application and the other one `'appname.apps.AppnameConfig'`.

What is the difference between the two ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally, items listed in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` are Python packages. Generally if you install a third party package, it's imported more or less directly. For example, if I make a `my_django_addon` package, I would include it as such, after bundling it as a Python package and installing it with `easy_install`, `pip`, etc.

An alternative is to point not to the package itself, but to a Django [appconfig](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#configuring-applications). This newer approach doesn't point *directly* to the Python package itself, but rather, a configuration object with some extra metadata.

Comment: @AndreiGrigorev thanks, yeah she's mine -- a red heeler. Unfortunately she just passed away though. She'll be missed. :(

Comment: Feels bad. Rest in peace :(